# How to filter and return specific object value from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects(data from BE) I need to filter by one specific value and return a list of the IDs of those objects.

This will return the whole object, so i could run in a for loop and append to a new array but seems lengthy.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "One",
    canAcceptRecruits: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Two",
    canAcceptRecruits: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Three",
    canAcceptRecruits: false
  }, {
    id: 50,
    name: "Fifty",
    canAcceptRecruits: true
  }
];

console.log(data.filter(x => x.canAcceptRecruits == true));
```

I know i can use a map or a reducer to perform the operation, but i was wondering if there is anything more succinct, nicer perhaps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have a `canAcceptRecruits` property on any of those objects. Also: `comstants` looks like a typo.

Comment: thanks, the array i put down is an example array to display what im after i cant post the actual contents of the array object for obvious reasons, I will modify to get the actual object value i require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.map` seems like the best option.

```js
const ids = this.props.constants.divisions
  .filter((x) => x.canAcceptRecruits == true)
  .map(x => x.id);
```

Comment: can shorten a bit if needed `((x) => x.canAcceptRecruits)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array.forEach` and loop only once. might be alittle faster than `filter + map`

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: "One", canAcceptRecruits: true  }, {  id: 2, name: "Two", canAcceptRecruits: true  },  {  id: 3, name: "Three", canAcceptRecruits: false  }, { id: 50, name: "Fifty", canAcceptRecruits: true }]

let result = [];

data.forEach(x => {if(x.canAcceptRecruits) result.push(x.id)})
console.log(result)
```